# Powershell - Windows.Clipboard not found

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, clipboard

I have a problem with Powershell and cmd. I have a script that reference the clipboard

```
[System.Windows.Clipboard]::SetText("My text");
```

I run the script in the Powershell editor and eveything goes fine. When I tried running it from the commandline

```
powershell.exe -c myscript.ps1
```

I get this error: Type [System.Windows.Clipboard] not found

(I translate it from French, I suppose this is the equivalent in english)

Any idea?

Comment: run this first `Add-Type -Assembly PresentationCore`

Comment: That solves my problems! Thanks @AnthonyStringer :)

Answer (score 2):

Like @AnthonyStringer said, I had to import first the PresentationCore with the command

```
Add-Type -Assembly PresentationCore
```

This way, when calling powershell from the cmd it was able to call Windows.Clipboard.